# MariaDB error with Wordpress after migration

Tags: wordpress, migration, mariadb

After migration to new server (Debian) i have a problem with my website (CMS Wordpress)

```
B\xc5\x82\xc4\x85d You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'AND comment_type = '' AND post_password = ''\r\n\tORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LI' at line 7 bazy danych WordPressa podczas wykonywania zapytania SELECT ID, post_title, post_password, comment_ID,\r\n\tcomment_post_ID, 
comment_author, comment_author_email, comment_date_gmt, comment_approved,\r\n\tcomment_type,comment_author_url,\r\n\tSUBSTRING(comment_content,1,65) AS com_excerpt\r\n\tFROM wp_comments\r\n\tLEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts ON 
(wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID)\r\n\tWHERE comment_approved = '1' AND comment_author= AND comment_type = '' AND post_password = ''\r\n\tORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 5 wys\xc5\x82anego przez 
require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/newspaper/archive.php'), get_sidebar, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/newspaper/sidebar-user.php'), 
dynamic_sidebar, WP_Widget->display_callback, TJ_Widget_Tabs_User->widget, tj_tabs_comments_user, referer: http://tools.opoint.com/AI/art_info.php?id_link=12072016755
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You've lost the value in `comment_author=`

Comment: Were you hoping for `Błąd` ?